# Post form while retaining get variables

Tags: php, forms, post, get

This seems so simple but I can't remember how I've done it before.

Using PHP I'm posting a form from mysite.com/?x=y and want the resulting page to be mysite.com/?x=y&formx=formy...

Options I've tried don't quite give the desired result:

**action** - setting `action="?x=y"` clears the get variables if `method="get"` in place of those in the form. Prior knowledge of the get variables are also required.

**method** - although it seems logical to set `method="get"`, this passes the form variables but clears any placed in action. Setting `method="post"` retains the current get variables but doesn't add the form variables/values.

**Hidden field(s)** - All get variables/values can be in hidden fields with `method="get"`. This requires prior knowledge of the get variables and a lot of duplication if there are a lot of variables or forms. *This so far is the closest solution.*

Answer (score 2):

Just set the form's "method" attribute to "get" instead of "post".

Example:

```
<form action="?x=y" method="get">
<input type="text" name="query" size="20">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could :

- either pass those variables as `<input type="hidden" name="x" vaue="y" />` in your form.
- or, maybe this might work : use "`mysite.com/?x=y`" as `action` for your form : with a bit of luck, those parameters will remain when the browser will post your form -- you should try, but it might work.

Of course, if you want those parameters to appear in the URL of the destination page, you'll have to use the GET `method` for your form.